# Walkthrough: Creating a simple data application by using ADO.NET

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio

I am following tutorial on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj943772.aspx
Has anyone finished this project?

When I am doing it, the buttons in navigation don't seem to respond...any help will be very welcome.

Another issue is as follows:-

I am sorry Fran Tan, I should have included the code. I thought someone has done it and can show me the right course. Indeed this happened so thank you Alex W. It was matter of double clicking on the buttons to create button click method. I would like to ask: The app has been build and published and when I try to enter a new customer it comes back with the message: 'Customer ID was not returned. Account could not be created'.: //NC-10 try-catch-finally

```
try
{
    //NC-11 Open the connection.
    conn.Open();

    //NC-12 Run the stored procedure.
    cmdNewCustomer.ExecuteNonQuery();

    //NC-13 Customer ID is an IDENTITY value from the database. 
    this.parsedCustomerID = (int)cmdNewCustomer.Parameters["@CustomerID"].Value;
    this.txtCustomerID.Text = Convert.ToString(parsedCustomerID);
}
catch
{
    //NC-14 A simple catch.
   MessageBox.Show("Customer ID was not returned. Account could not be created.");
}
finally
{
    //NC-15 Close the connection.
    conn.Close();
}
```

and this is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Sales].[uspNewCustomer]
    @CustomerName NVARCHAR (40),
    @CustomerID INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [Sales].[Customer] (CustomerName) 
    VALUES (@CustomerName);

    SET @CustomerID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    RETURN @@ERROR
END
GO
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question would be better if you included the code and a more detailed description of expected versus observed behavior. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As it currently stands, your question could be considered off-topic.

Comment: Its possible that you have the btn click methods in the code but did not assign an event handler to execute when the use clicks the button. When you are in the form designer, double click on one of the buttons, that will automatically create the button click method for you and also create the event handler assignment.

Comment: Show us your HTML or serve side code.

Comment: I see no values set for the parameters? This sproc expects a name as an input param and the id as an output param.